# Can someone explain the difference between Structure and Taxonomy?

Tags: module, structure, taxonomy

I'm trying to pick a navigation module that will dynamically update the main nav, secondary navigation, and landing pages as pages are added, keeping everything consistent. This is a requirement because otherwise the client will make a mess out of the navigation, making it inconsistent and ruining the user experience.

From my research it seems NavEE is not the answer. It appears to be fully manual. Can someone explain the difference between Taxonomy and Structure, when you would choose one or the other, etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure is the only self-contained solution to have a completely automated, whole-site navigation for every Pages URI that is *automatically* kept up to date as the end user adds new pages or changes the overall Pages URI hierarchy. But Structure is more of a whole-hog commitment to how you set up and build your site (some like this, others do not). In other words, Structure is not just for navigation it's a way of building sites with EE.

Both NavEE and Taxonomy (my personal favorite) are *just for navigation*, are very open-ended, and require more hands-on approach from the end user. They also require a more savvy, or better-educated, end user. The upside is that they are really flexible and make no assumptions about how you're setting up your site *or* your navigation.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Does Taxonomy have at least a partial dynamic aspect to it? Can't clients create a page, select to make it part of the nav, and the page appears on the nav?

Comment: Oh, absolutely, yes. But they do have to take that step, whereas with Structure they would not.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'm leaning towards Taxonomy. Structure makes me nervous. It's like it turns EE into a different CMS.